# How to send this with php mail function

Tags: php, jquery, email

I would like all additional input of benodigheden and ingrediënten are also sent. However, I do not know how you could pick up the cost of additional input. I hope somebody can help me.

This is my code

```
<div id="versturen">
        <?php
        if(isset ($_POST['Verzenden']))
        {
            $name = $_POST['Naam'];
            $Email = $_POST['Email'];
            $opmerking = $_POST ['Opmerking'];
            $seizoen = $_POST ['Seizoen'];
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/           
            /*---benodigheden---begin---*/ 
            $benodigheden1 = $_POST ['benodigheden1'];
            /*---benodigheden---eind---*/ 
            /*---ingrediënten---begin---*/ 
            $ingrediënten1 = $_POST ['ingrediënten1'];
            /*---ingrediënten---eind---*/ 
            $stappenplan = $_POST['stappenplan'];
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            $opmerking = $_POST ['Opmerking'];
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/   
            $subject = 'GERECHT INDIENEN' . $seizoen . '' ; 
            $to = 'wross@live.nl, wvanhees35@hotmail.com';
            $gerecht = 'BENODIGHEDEN <br />' . $benodigheden1 .  '<br /> NGREDIËNTEN <br />'    . $ingrediënten1 .  '<br /> STAPPENPLAN <br />'. $stappenplan . '<br />';




            $message = ''.$gerecht . $opmerking . ' Dit gerecht is ingestuurd door ' . $name .  ' en is ingediend via ' .$Email; 

            mail($to, $subject, $message, "From:" . $Email)
        ?>
        <div id="testing"><br /><h2>Uw mail is verzonden</h2></div>
        <?php
        header("Refresh: 3; URL=../index.php");
        }
        else{
        ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <legend>Neem contact op</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="Naam">Naam: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="Naam" name="Naam" placeholder="Naam" required="required" />
                    </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="Email">Email :</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="email" id="Email"name="Email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="Seizoen">Seizoen: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>                                                                  
                        <select name="Seizoen" id="Seizoen" required>
                        <option value="">Kies hier je seizoen</option>
                            <option value="Lente">Lente</option>
                            <option value="Zomer">Zomer</option>
                            <option value="Herfst">Herfst</option>
                            <option value="Winter">Winter</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <hr />  
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="benodigheden1">Benodigheden:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="benodigheden1"name="benodigheden1" placeholder="Benodigheden" required="required" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="ingrediënten1">Ingrediënten:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="ingrediënten1"name="ingrediënten1" placeholder="Ingrediënten" required="required" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="stappenplan">Stappenplanm:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea name="stappenplan" id="stappenplan" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Stappenplan" required="required" /></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <hr />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="Opmerking">Opmerking:</label>
                        </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea name="Opmerking" id="Opmerking" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Opmerking" required="required" /></textarea>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Verzenden" name="Verzenden" /></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form> 
        <?php
            };
        ?>              

        </div>
```

Here is a link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vtu8wn1c/1/). 
He does not address here all my code (just as here).

Comment: What do you mean with "how you could pick up the cost of additional input"

Comment: With the javascript do I create several input fields. This I would like to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name the original and newly spawned input fields ingredienten[] and benodigheden[]

this will make them come in as a array in php.

```
foreach($_POST['benodigheden'] as $value){
    echo $value .'<br />';
}
```

offcourse you need to change it to something usefull

I made a example [see jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ruk8qquw/) place the above php somewhere and see wat happens if you submit

changed the html form input fields

```
<input type="text" id="benodigheden1"name="benodigheden[]" placeholder="Benodigheden" required="required" />
<input type="text" id="ingrediënten1"name="ingrediënten[]" placeholder="Ingrediënten" required="required" />
```

changed the javascript by adding this line " .attr('name',res[0]+'[]') "

```
// Add a line, and make it non-mandatory
$(this).clone()
    .attr('id', newId).removeAttr('required')
    .attr('name',res[0]+'[]')
    .val('')
    .insertAfter(this)
    .before($('<br>'));
```

Comment: It didn't work I have now this: $benodigheden = $_POST ['benodigheden'];
    foreach($_POST['benodigheden'] as $value){
     echo $value .'<br />';

Comment: Make sure you change the name of you input fields and the jquery to add a new input field. " <input name='benodigheden[]' /> " see the brackets at the end instead of the number, this way the $_POST value for benodigdheden will be a array if its benodigdheden1 benodigdheden2 etc the above wont work.